# Telethon: Is there a way to download messages faster from a channel?

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I am downloading all messages from a channel with two million messages, and the few initial 5K messages get downloaded fast, but then I assume Telegram does throttling somehow on their side. Is there a way to improve this so it doesn't take ages ? This is the class I wrote that worked well with channels with few thousand messages.

```
class TelegramMessages(TelegramSession):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.msg_json_path = os.path.join(
            self.telegram_data_path, self.group + '_group_messages' + '.json')

    def write_messages_to_file(self, msg_list):
        with open(self.msg_json_path, 'w') as file:
            file.write(json.dumps(msg_list, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str, ensure_ascii=False))

    async def get_msg_list(self):

        self.logging.info(
            'Downloading message list from Telegram channel ...' + self.group)

        msg_list = []

        async for message in self.client.iter_messages(self.group):
            try:

                msg_dict = message.to_dict()
                msg_list.append(msg_dict)
                self.write_messages_to_file(msg_list)

            except AttributeError as a_error:
                self.logging.warning(
                    str(a_error) + '<-- found missing data in message')
               

    def trigger_message_loop(self):
        if os.path.isfile(self.msg_json_path):

            self.logging.info('JSON message file is already here,skipping')
            pass

        else:
            self.client = TelegramClient(
                self.full_session_path, self.api_id, self.api_hash)
            self.client.start(self.phone_number)
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            loop.run_until_complete((self.get_msg_list()))
            self.client._disconnect()
```

Any hint or improvement is welcome!

Comment: Yes, Telegram does throttle every request. You may want to do a [`takeout`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.account.AccountMethods.takeout).

Comment: Thanks, I just implemented it and it works much better now